# Serve index.html at / by default in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have a static file called `index.html` that I'd like to serve when someone requests `/`. Usually web servers [do this by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index), but Compojure doesn't. How can I make Compojure serve `index.html` when someone requests `/`?

Here's the code I'm using for the static directory:

```
; match anything in the static dir at resources/public
(route/resources "/")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This would be a pretty simple Ring middleware:

```
(defn wrap-dir-index [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (handler
     (update-in req [:uri]
                #(if (= "/" %) "/index.html" %)))))
```

Just wrap your routes with this function, and requests for `/` get transformed into requests for `/index.html` before the rest of your code sees them.

```
(def app (-> (routes (your-dynamic-routes)
                     (resources "/"))
             (...other wrappers...)
             (wrap-dir-index)))
```

Comment: I guess my point is: Compojure doesn't do this, because it's easy to do with Ring instead. Your Clojure web stack is not one all-encompassing platform, but a series of pluggable and specialized tools. Solve problem X with the tool that's designed for it.

Answer (score 41):

An alternative could be to create either a redirect or a direct response in an additional route. Like so:

```
(ns compj-test.core
  (:use [compojure.core])
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.util.response :as resp]))

(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] (resp/file-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
  (GET "/a" [] (resp/resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))
```

The "/" route returns a file response of "index.html" which is present in the public folder. The "/a" route responds directly by 'inlineing' the file index.html.

More on ring responses: https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/wiki/Creating-responses

EDIT: removed unnecessary `[ring.adapter.jetty]` import.

Comment: Hi. (GET "/" [] (resp/resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))  works perfectly for me.

Comment: Be careful with not providing the content-type you want. Another middleware such as `wrap-content-type` could break your code. I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32491623/1707589) addressing this.

Answer (score 28):

```
(ns compj-test.core
  (:use [compojure.core])
  (:require
        [ring.util.response :as resp]))

(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] (resp/redirect "/index.html")))
```

What you're asking for is a redirect from / to /index.html.  Its as simple as *(resp/redirect target)*. No need to over complicate things.

Comment: this was the most straight forward and logical response, thanks!

Answer (score 19):

This works just fine. No need to write a ring middle-ware.

```
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io])

(defroutes app-routes 
(GET "/" [] (io/resource "public/index.html")))
```

Comment: Don't know if it answers the question but it helped me for what I needed! Upvoted! Thanks!

Comment: Be careful with not providing the content-type you want. Another middleware such as `wrap-content-type` could break your code. I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32491623/1707589) addressing this.

Answer (score 13):

After viewing a lot of the answers here, I'm using the following code:

```
(ns app.routes
  (:require [compojure.core :refer [defroutes GET]]
            [ring.util.response :as resp]))

(defroutes appRoutes
  ;; ...
  ;; your routes
  ;; ...
  (GET "/" []
       (resp/content-type (resp/resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}) "text/html"))))
```

- No redirects;
- No need of another middleware;
- index.html stays in the right folder (resources/public/index.html);
- It works with other middleware (a lot of the answers break when using with some ring default middleware);
- It provides content-type so it works with wrap-content-type middleware.

Check [ring-defaults](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-defaults). It has best practices middleware you should use on your projects.

Comment: Get form is missing empty parameters [], otherwise this is just what I needed, thanks!

Comment: @hequ Thanks! Updated the answer with those missing brackets.

Comment: Shouldn't `resp/content-type` be wrapped in a form?

Answer (score 3):

Recently I discovered that @amalloy's answer doesn't work when the Clojure/Compojure app is run under Jetty or Tomcat as a .war. In this case `:path-info` needs to be updated. Also, I think this version will handle any route, not just the "root" route.

```
(defn- wrap-dir-index [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (handler
     (let [k (if (contains? request :path-info) :path-info :uri) v (get request k)]
       (if (re-find #"/$" v)
         (assoc request k (format "%sindex.html" v))
         request)))))
```

See also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/compojure/yzvpQVeQS3w/RNFkFJaAaYIJ

**UPDATED:** Replaced example with a version that works.

Answer (score 1):

when other code doesnt work,
try this code.

```
(GET "/about/" [] (ring.util.response/content-type
                     (ring.util.response/resource-response "about/index.html" {:root "public"}) "text/html"))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to make it more useful for other readers.

Comment: Great answer. It provides a resource specifying its content-type using ring provided solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a consideration Binita, a gotcha I have been experiencing. Despite I couldn't find any documentation regarding importance of order defining Compojure routes I find out that this doesn't work

```
(GET "/*" [] r/static) 
(GET "/" [] (clojure.java.io/resource "public/index.html"))
```

while this does work

```
(GET "/" [] (clojure.java.io/resource "public/index.html"))
(GET "/*" [] r/static)
```

Obviously the  `*` matchs also the empty string but I thought that the order shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: Be careful with not providing the content-type you want. Another middleware such as `wrap-content-type` could break your code. I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32491623/1707589) addressing this.