# Serving index.html file from compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm new to clojure and compojure and trying out the compojure along with ring to create a basic web application.

here is my handler.clj

```
(ns gitrepos.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.util.response :as resp]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] (resp/file-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults))
```

i have this **index.html** file under **/resources/public** but the application is not rendering this html file. Instead getting **Not found**

I have searched a lot it, even this [Serve index.html at / by default in Compojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729628/serve-index-html-at-by-default-in-compojure) does not seems to resolve the issue.

Not sure what am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try use some template library, such as [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer). So you can do something like this:

```
(defroutes myapp
  (GET "/hello/" []
    (render-string (read-template "templates/hello.html"))))
```

Or passing some value:

```
(defroutes myapp
  (GET "/hello/" [name]
    (render-string (read-template "templates/hello.html") {name: "Jhon"})))
```

And, as @piotrek-Bzdyl said:

```
(GET  "/" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
```

Comment: that seems better option, tried clostache, it worked, Thanks.

Comment: Nice! Yes, clostache is also a option

Answer (score 1):

Naveen

Here is a snippet of my own that seems to work. In comparison with yours, you do not have a resource path in `defroutes`:

```
(defroutes default-routes
  (route/resources "public")
  (route/not-found
   "<h1>Resource you are looking for is not found</h1>"))

(defroutes app
  (wrap-defaults in-site-routes site-defaults)
  (wrap-defaults test-site-routes site-defaults)
  (wrap-restful-format api-routes)
  (wrap-defaults default-routes site-defaults))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need specify your routing for serving files from `resoures/public` using `file-response` at this directory will be served thanks to `site-defaults`. The only part you are missing is mapping `/` path to `/index.html` which can be done with the code you mentioned from another question. So the solution would be:

```
(defn wrap-dir-index [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (handler
      (update
        req
        :uri
        #(if (= "/" %) "/index.html" %)))))

(defroutes app-routes
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
    (wrap-defaults site-defaults)
    (wrap-dir-index)
```

On a side note, you should prefer using `ring.util.response/resource-response` as it serves files from classpath and will work also when you package you app into a jar file. `file-response` uses file system to locate files and won't work from inside jar file.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what is wrong with my answer? I would be more than happy to fix it or delete it if I know why it's wrong.