# Match and GET request in Compojure for react-router browserHistory

Tags: clojure, compojure

I want to serve the following route for any GET request path so that I can use a frontend routing library instead (react-router).

```
(GET "/" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
```

This it what I have tried:

```
(GET "/*" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
(rfn [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
(GET "/:any{.*}" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
(GET "/*" [] (ring.util.response/content-type
                     (ring.util.response/resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}) "text/html"))
(GET "/*" [] (clojure.java.io/resource "public/index.html"))
```

They all give the same error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:5000/index.css".
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And the Unexpected token is the first `<` in `index.html`

So my question is how can I adapt my Compojure/Ring/Immutant stack to play nice with react-router?

UPDATE:
I have also tried the following midleware, to change all request to the root but with no luck:

```
(defn wrap-dir-index [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (handler
     (assoc req :uri "/"))))
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828884/serving-index-html-file-from-compojure/35829722#35829722 - when you use that code, all your files from `resources/public` will be served by the server and all paths ending with `/` will serve `/index.html`.

Comment: I want every GET to serve /index.html, not just the one ending with /. I have updated my question with other alternatives but still im not able to get things working as i want.

Comment: What about other resources like javascript and css? Are they all embedded in your index.html? Or maybe you want to serve whatever you have in `resources/public` and fallback to serving `index.html` if a specific resource is not found?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what im trying to do :) However when trying to use the code from the suggested post it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wrap-resource` as described on [Ring wiki page](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Static-Resources) combined with a catch all route:

```
(defroutes handler
  (GET "/" []
    (-> (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"})
        (content-type "text/html))
  (GET "/*" [] (redirect "/")))

(def app
  (-> handler
      (wrap-resource "public")
      (wrap-content-type)
      (wrap-not-modified))
```

I think it's better to redirect from all other URLs to "/" so your application works always using the same base address.