# ring response downloads index.html instead of rendering it

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I have an `index.html` located in `resources/public/index.html` and have defined the following routes (application is split up more than this, just making the code concise):

```
(ns example.example
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]))

(defroutes routes
           (GET "/" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"} "text/html")))

(defroutes application-routes
           routes
           (route/resources "/")
           (route/not-found (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"} "text/html")))


(def application
  (wrap-defaults application-routes site-defaults))
```

However, when I go to `localhost:8090/` it downloads the html file instead of rendering it.

If I go to `localhost:8090/index.html` it renders the file properly so I assumed my routing is incorrect somehow but after looking at examples I am not too sure why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File is downloaded instead of being displayed in the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548372/file-is-downloaded-instead-of-being-displayed-in-the-browser)

Comment: This exact problem is resolved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729628/serve-index-html-at-by-default-in-compojure).

Comment: @kongeor using `resp/redirect` still causes the html file to be downlaoded not rendered

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same issue with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729628/serve-index-html-at-by-default-in-compojure).

You need to create a middleware to update your request:

```
(defn wrap-dir-index [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (handler
     (update-in req [:uri]
                #(if (= "/" %) "/index.html" %)))))
```

And then wrap your routes:

```
(def app
  (wrap-dir-index (wrap-defaults app-routes site-defaults)))
```

Complete [handler.clj](https://gist.github.com/kongeor/b4c764a017482961bcfc9cb845e58c29).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
          [ring.middleware.resource :as resource])

(defroutes routes

     (GET "/" []
             (io/resource "index.html")))
```

Also use middleware for resource wrapping

```
(resource/wrap-resource "/public")
```